# How to toggle readonly_fields in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, admin

Need to add button to django admin page, if you want to edit Model, you push **Edit** then edit what you need, and save it. When you open it after saving, it must be uneditable again. So, how to do that?

I have simple admin.py code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Order

class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['__str__', 'email', 'project_type', 'price']
    list_filter = ['email', 'first_name', 'project_type', 'price']
    readonly_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone', 'project_type', 'price')
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone', 'project_type', 'services', 'price', 'slug')

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
```

Comment: I don't understand, it must editable at creation, but not at edition? What's the condition to it being editable?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this, first of all need to **create new boolean field** (in my case named *is_editable*) in **models.py** and set default value to false. Then paste my code to admin.py:

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj: # if object is created
        if obj.is_editable == False:
            return ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone', 'project_type', 'services',  'price', 'slug']
        else:
            return []
    else:
        return []
```

now, if you want to edit your model, you need to check this boolean, and only then edit.